# How should I split the profit on sales of a house?

Tags: real-estate, profitability

Is there a formula to split profit after sale of a house, two people put in 15000 each and  one parent put in 35000 to help offset mortgage.

Comment: There is no single way to do this; many different things could be considered 'fair', or legal, but what really matters is the understanding / agreement at the time the house was purchased / the funds were leant. Was this discussed between all parties in the past?

Comment: don't forget the who made the monthly payments, and who paid for repairs.

Answer (score 3):

The one you all agreed on when everybody invested their money in the first place would be good.

Failing that, you need to know how much each party put in, including the person who was paying the mortgage.  Then divide it proportionally to each of their investments.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of formulas you could use, but the parties involved will have to decide what is fair for themselves.